# twoWay binding is not working in ToggleButton with ObservableCollection as the source

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I successfully bind two `ToggleButton`'s to an `ObservableCollection<VMData>`, the button's `IsChecked` state is where I get a problem:

XAML:

```
<ToggleButton Content="One" x:Name="ToggleButtonOne" Margin="10,20,0,0" Width="100"
          Command="{Binding ToggleButtonClicked_Command}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButtonOne}"
          IsChecked="{Binding VMDataInfoSet[0].Running, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<ToggleButton Content="Two" x:Name="ToggleButtonTwo" Margin="10,10,0,0" Width="100"
          Command="{Binding ToggleButtonClicked_Command}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButtonTwo}"
          IsChecked="{Binding VMDataInfoSet[1].Running, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In the ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<VMData> VMDataInfoSet { get; set; }

public class VMData
{
    public string MyType { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public double Qty { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public bool Running { get; set; }
}
```

When clicking on a `ToggleButton`, `VMDataInfoSet[0].Running` successfully updates to `true` from a state of `false`.  However when I set `VMDataInfoSet[0].Running` to `false` (when the `ToggleButton` is checked, aka `true`), via a simple method in the viewmodel, the `ToggleButton` remains "blue" and does not update back to an unchecked state. So I can update the `ObservableCollection` via the buttons, but I can't update the button via the `ObservableCollection`/code.

There are many similar questions on SO, especially for WPF. Though I can't figure this out yet. There is an issue with `OneWay` binding for a toggle button [here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/921). And I have tried adding `UpdateSourceTrigger` as in my example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533146/toggle-button-two-way-binding-not-working-universal-windows-platform).

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to implement the Interface INotifyPropertyChanged on your VMData class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JohnnyQ mentions in the comments, implement the INPC interface in VMDataClass:

```
public class VMData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string myType;
    private string iD;
etc

    public string MyType
    {
        get { return myType; }
        set
        {
            myType = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyType");
        }
    }
    public string ID
    {
        {
            iD = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }
etc

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```